# Change the root password

Tags: server, password, root

I have used this procedure to change the root password:

1. Get to GRUB screen
2. Press <kbd>e</kbd> to edit
3. add `rw init=/bin/bash` to end of the kernel line
4. <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>x</kbd> to reboot
5. from there I would `mount -rw -o remount` / then `passwd`, etc...

That has worked in the past. This time I get:

```
bash: cannot set terminal process group (-1): Inappropriate ioctl for device
bash: no job control in this shell
root@(none):/#
```

Then nothing. No response to any keyboard entry.

I also tried to boot to the recovery mode but when I hit to "Drop to root shell prompt", it shows me the message:

```
Give root password for maintenance (or type Control-D to continue)
```

Comment: @Melebius I also checked this but when I came  "Drop to root shell prompt" it wants from me to write root password.

Comment: I checked this @Fabbyit requires root password.

Comment: @Melebius I am using the arrow keys scroll down to root  when I hit to  "Drop to root shell prompt"  ,it shows me "Give root password for maintenance (or type Control-D to continue)" message

Comment: It didn't make difference .I edited question

Comment: It takes a peer review I beleive but the edits will show up.

Comment: Normally Ubuntu has not activated log in as user `root`. Instead you are encouraged to have at least one user, that can use `sudo` (with their own user password). Maybe there is a userID with `sudo` permissions, that can do system tasks.

Comment: @EliahKagan this link helps me .I solved .There is a answer of my error in this link .I mounted wrong partition.Thanks a lot.

Comment: None of the so called duplicates are helpful at all because eventually they just come down "use init=/bin/bash" which then drops you to this ioctl message and that's the end of it because after tihis error message bash doesn't accept any keystrokes. Not even ctrl+alt+del.